# Name for cuts which result in shapes that are rotatable images of one another

Tags: geometry, terminology, rotations, symmetry, reflection

I'm looking for the technical term to describe any line that cuts through a shape such that the two pieces are a rotation of one another.

[image: Examples]

Obviously any line of reflective symmetry fulfils this property, but there are often other lines that have this property as well, e.g. 4th example from the left in the image below. Indeed for a square there are an infinite number of such lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any such cut must pass through a twofold rotation axis of the object, so they may be simply called *cuts through a twofold axis*.